# Solution to $u''(x)-V(x)u(x) = 0$ is identically zero

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am struggling to prove a property of a solution to the following ODE:

> Suppose $u\in \mathcal{C}([a,b])$ is twice continuously
> differentiable, $V\in\mathcal{C}([a,b])$, $V(x)\geq 0$ $\forall x \in
> > [a,b]$, and $$u''(x) - V(x)u(x)=0 \quad x\in[a,b],$$ $$u(a)=u(b)=0.$$
> Then $u(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$.

I've tried a few different things to prove this. We know that $u$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and since $u(a)=u(b)=0$, then by Rolle's theorem $\exists c\in(a,b)$ such that $u'(c)=0.$ Then I would want to somehow prove that $u'(x)=0$ over the whole interval, meaning that $u$ is constant at 0, but I am not sure how to get there.

Something else I noticed was that from the equation we have that $u''(a)=u''(b)=0$, so by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$0=f''(b)-f''(a)=\int_a^b f'''(x)\mathrm{d}x,$$ where by the product rule, $u'''(x) = V(x)u'(x) + V'(x)u(x)$. Then I thought to proceed via integration by parts, but I didn't get anywhere that way either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe apply Taylor's theorem to have a 2nd order error term and use ODE to write $u''(x)$ in terms of $u(x)$ and solve. Not sure it will work but seems perhaps like smth to try.

Comment: Assume $u$ has positive values, then $u$ has a maximum where at the same time $u(x)>0$ and $u''(x)<0$. But that is not possible,...

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2998720/42969

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the integral

$$E = \int_a^b (u')^2\:dx \geq 0$$

and integrate by parts

$$E = uu'\Bigr|_a^b-\int_a^b uu''\:dx = 0 +\int_a^b - (Vu^2)\:dx \leq 0$$

since the integrand is strictly nonpositive $(-Vu^2\leq 0)$. This implies $E = 0$, therefore

$$u'= 0 \implies u = 0$$

identically on $[a,b]$, due to the boundary conditions.